# Guidance for improving my proof writeups for undergraduate analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am currently enrolled in undergraduate real analysis and my Teacher's Assistant has assigned the point total of (1/5) to two of my graded questions. He stated that my proofs were 'poorly written' and declined to change my grade after I guided him through the proofs. I understand his dogma, but he did not comment on how my proofs could be improved, so I am still confused about why my proofs were hard to read.

I do believe that the proofs are correct, but I apologize if they are hard to follow. The first problem is Rudin's Exercise 29 from Chapter 2, and that the second problem is the University of California: Los Angeles Basic Exam (Fall, 2005) Question 5.

$(1)$

> Prove that every open set in $R$ is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments.

---

> Proof. We let $E \subset R$ be an open set and let $x \in E$. We take $a_x = \inf \{z \in R : [z,x] \in E\}$ and $b_x = \sup \{z \in R: [x,z] \in E\}$. If $a_x$ does not exist, we define it to be $-\infty$. If $b_x$ does not exist, we define it to be $\infty$.
>
> We show that this interval $(a_x, b_x)$ is the maximum interval in $E$ that contains $x$. We see that the interval $(a_x,b_x) \subset E$, since if not then some interval $(a,b)$ with $a < x < b$ and with $a_x < a$ or $b < b_x$ must be contained in $E$ (since $x$ is an interior point of $E$). Without loss of generality, suppose $a_x < a$. Then $[a,x] \in \{z \in R : [z,x] \in E\}$, since if not then $a_x$ would not be the greatest lower bound to its defined set. Hence, $(a_x, b_x) \subset E$. We also see that $(a_x, b_x)$ is the maximum interval in $E$ that contains $x$. Suppose there is some larger interval $(a,b) \supset (a_x, b_x)$ with $a < a_x$ or $b_x < b$ and $(a,b) \in E$. Without loss of generality, suppose $a < a_x$. Then there is some $q \in R$ such that $a < q < a_x$, so $[q,x] \in E$, a contradiction.
>
> We now show that when $y \in E$ then either $(a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$ or $(a_x, b_x) \cap (a_y, b_y) = \emptyset$. We suppose that $(a_x, b_x) \cap (a_y, b_y) \neq \emptyset$. Trivially, we have that $(a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y) \in E$ is open. We then have that $(a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y)$ is a connected set, and so we have that $(a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y)$ is a segment, since we could take $a_{xy} = \inf\{x \in (a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y): x\}$ and $b_{xy} = \sup\{x \in (a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y): x\}$ and so we would have that $(a_{xy}, b_{xy}) = (a_x, b_x) \cup (a_y, b_y)$. Hence, we have by the above results that $(a_x, b_x) = (a_y, b_y)$ and hence we have the result.

$(2)$

> Prove carefully that $R^2$ is not a (countable) union of sets $S_i$ $\left(i = 1,2,\dotsc\right)$ with each $S_i$ being a subset of some straight line $L_i$ in $R^2$.

---

> We see that if a countable union of straight lines $L_i$ $(i = 1,2,\dotsc)$ does not cover $R^2$, then a countable union of subsets of straight lines do not cover $R^2$, since $ \bigcup S_i \subset \bigcup L_i \subsetneq R^2$. We now see that if disjoint lines do not cover $R^2$ then non-disjoint lines do not cover $R^2$, since we could suppose that some set of lines $\{L_i\}$ cover $R^2$, then there must be a subset $\{L_j\}$ that is disjoint that covers $R^2$, since if not then there must be some line $L_k$ such that $L_k \cap \{L_j\} = \emptyset$ for every disjoint subset $\{L_j\} \subset \{L_i\}$. We see that every other line in the full set must interset with the line $L_k$ at most countably many times and thus not fulfilling the uncountable cardinality that the line demands and thus not covering $R^2$. Hence, we restrict our argument to a set of disjoint lines $\{L_j\}$.
>
> We now show that a set of disjoint lines $\{L_j\}$ cannot cover $R^2$. Without loss of generality, suppose that the lines are not parallel to the line $(r,0)$ with $r \in R$. Then we define a line's position from $(0,0)$ as the point that it intersects the line $(r,0)$. Since there are only countably many intersections, we have that the set does not cover $(r,0)$ and thus not $R^2$. Hence, we have the result.

Comment: This is two distinct questions.  You are more likely to get useful feedback if you ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the website. Should I delete this question and resubmit as two distinct questions?

Comment: Addendum:  your first proof shows that we can write an open set as a disjoint union of open intervals.  How do you know that the union is countable?  In the second proof, you assume that you can choose the lines to be disjoint, but your reasoning is suspect (for each point $P(\theta) = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ on the unit circle, define the line $L_{\theta}$ which passes through the origin and $P(\theta)$; this collection covers $\mathbb{R}^2$, but all the lines intersect, so there is no disjoint subset).

Comment: Ah yes, for (1) I should have noted that every open subset must contain a rational point and so the union of the sets must be at most countable. I do believe that my reasoning for (2) is still correct, since your example requires an uncountable number lines.

Comment: You say "disjoint" but you probably mean "pairwise disjoint". The expression $L_k \cap \{L_j\}$ doesn't really make sense. ($L_k$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ while $\{L_j\}$ is a collection of lines.) Perhaps you mean $L_k \cap \bigcup_j L_j$. Anyway, this whole disjointness thing is a total distraction. Just let $r$ be a real number not occurring as the slope of any of your countably many lines, and proceed as you did (you only get countably many points on lines of slope $r$), no need for any disjointness.

Comment: Yes, my example requires uncountably many lines (that is, in fact, the thing that you are trying to prove).  But you can't assume willy-nilly that every covering set of lines contains a disjoint subcollection.

Comment: I suppose then that it would have been clearer to state that the subset $\{L_j\}$ constitutes of some set of lines that are pairwise disjoint such that each line $L_j \subset \{L_i\}$.

Comment: No, that would not have been clearer. The expression $L_j \subset \{L_i\}$ still doesn't make sense. $L_j$ is a line, a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The elements of $L_j$ are points in the plane. The elements of $\{L_i\}$ are lines. Also, you have NOT given a proof that there is a pairwise disjoint subcover. The "since if not then there must be some line $L_k$ such that..." (such that $L_k$ meets every pairwise disjoint subset) makes no sense. Just as a general piece of advice, do not use proof by contradiction within a proof by contradiction!

Comment: Sorry, I suppose $L_j \in \{L_i\}$ would have been clearer. As you said above, I should have said that $L_k \cap \bigcup L_j = \emptyset$. The proof should make sense then. I am not showing that there is a pairwise disjoint subcover, I am showing that there must be, for otherwise we would have a contradiction.

Comment: It is bad form to define something that doesn't exist. In the first paragraph of the first proof. you could write " Define $a_x$ and $b_x$ in the extended reals $\Bbb R\cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$ as .... ".  The 2nd to 5th  sentences of the 2nd paragraph are a proof that $(a_x,b_x)\subset E.$ and should say so. Omit  "this interval " from "this interval $(a_x,b_x)$", And your "WLOG" is incorrect. It's NOT wlog, You can say, however, that "The other case is handled similarly."

Comment: BTW in the first Q it would be easier to define  $A(x)= \cup (\{[a,b]: a<x<b \land [a,b]\subset E\}. $ This is the same set as $(a_x,b_x) $ but it's obvious that $A(x)\subset E$.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help everyone. Honestly, I was expecting some need for a major overhaul given the grader's remarks, but I suppose that I will focus on showcasing the overall layout of my proofs to guide the reader. More importantly, I think that I need to overall prove to the grader that I am able to write well-written proofs. I think that he first dismissed my proofs off-hand because he was having a hard time understanding the structure, and so he based his current grade on a reoccurring trend of me having somewhat convoluted proofs.

Answer (score 3):

I will say that your proofs are hard to follow.  And, they don't show that you have much insight into the topology of the real numbers.

What does "countable" mean?

If there are countably many disjoint subsets, then there should be some way to put them into bijection with a subset of $\mathbb N$  Alternatively, you can find a 1-1 mapping to a set that you know is countable (the rationals perhaps).

I don't see any mapping.

The rationals are dense in $\mathbb R.$

Every open subset of $\mathbb R$ has elements in $\mathbb Q.$

From each subset disjoint subset of $\mathbb R$ we can choose a rational number as the representative of that set, and map the subsets of $\mathbb R$ to a subset of $\mathbb Q$

If $S$ is a line in $\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2$\ $S$ divides $\mathbb R^2$ into 2 disjoint open subsets.

If we have some collection of disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and we remove an additional line, we still have a collection of disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$